# How to handle three JDBC connectionpooling in tomcat?

Tags: java, jdbc

How to handle three database connection pool in tomcat 6 ? Three databases are(two oracle database and SQL server). Please advise what is the best to handle connections? Any any example code it will be more helpful to me.

I have seen examples of connectionpooling through JNDI. Is this best way to handle ?

Comment: *How to handle three database connection pool in tomcat* (despite the version), create three database connection resources. What have you tried?. *I have seen examples of connectionpooling through JNDI. Is this best way to handle?* Yes, it is, but you should **try it** instead just keep reading about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/

3CPO is another popular db connection pool. They have a lot of example code on their site.

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/